# Where can I find linux kernel config options and description?

Tags: linux, kernel

I am compiling a custom Linux kernel from the source tree, is there any place where all the Linux kernel config options and description is available. It is hard to find a description for each option and its use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Options with descriptions are specified in `Kconfig` in each subdirectoy. To see all of them, you need to concatenate all `Kconfig` files (e.g. using `find`), or you can do something like `make menuconfig`, where you have a hierarchical menu with descriptions as help texts.

The currently selected options are stored in the `.config` file in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps trying to write a kernel `.config` file manually from scratch? The kernel source Makefiles have built-in configuration tools: for example, run `make menuconfig` to get a text-based menu interface for configuring the kernel. See `Documentation/admin-guide/README.rst` for a complete list of configuration tools available.

**The configuration tools include a help function** that will be able to describe most options. Those options that don't have a help description tend to be one of the following:

- very new, possibly experimental parts of the kernel (so a help description has not been written yet - feel free to submit a patch to add a suitable description in this case).
- technical settings that are determined automatically based on other settings (for example, when you set the CPU type, a whole lot of settings are automatically set according to the features available in that CPU type)
- debugging settings that are intended for the developers of a particular driver or other kernel component only - if you need to change these, you should either be one of those developers or at least already contacting them.

The help texts come from the `Kconfig` files in each sub-directory of the kernel source code.